limiting excel columns to a maximum
After I import a csv file and double-click to make the columns wide enough to show data for each column contextually, many columns are way too wide.
Is there a routine I can run in an xlsx file that says "for each column, if its width is greater than 60, resize it to 60"?
even better would be a one-step routine, "set column widths to their data width, but no more than 60"
Ideally this could be saved so that I can run it in any spreadsheet - and with the 60 I mentioned above as a variable to enter with default 60.
Thanks

This requires VBA code.
From How to autofit column width up to maximum size?


Press Alt+F11
Click on Insert > Module


(Better wording than in original:)
3. Copy this code and then paste it in the new Window that should have opened :

   Sub mAutoWidth()
   Dim mCell As Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
   For Each mCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
     mCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
     If mCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth > 50 Then _
     mCell.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 50
   Next mCell
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub


Close the VBA editor with Alt+F4
Back in Excel use Alt + F8 to see the list of available Macros
Choose mAutoWidth and click Run


Replace 50 by 60 in the above code.

@Hannu: You have edited a quote. I am aware that it can be expressed better, but I wouldn't edit the text that I quote if it's good enough.

... not good enough for non-english speaker. Better for your liking like this?

@Hannu: I'm not going to argue, but that's a first time for me.

I'd like to call it "discussion" rather than  "arguing". :-}
